# C# Forms - Using a new folder in resources

Tags: c#, forms, resources, directory, new-operator

's me again. This is the problem, in C# forms in resource folder I have added another folder and named it Buttons. Coz' I love buttons. This is the question, how to use images/others from that folder?

My try so far:

```
        ThisBtnImg.Image = Properties.Resources.Buttons.ThisButton;
```

I have failed to see success in my attempts...
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the resource to the project. Go to project properties and then to tab "Resources". There you can add new resources and select images from disk.
Select resource type "Images" and then "Add Resource->Add existing file".

Comment: Yes, I did that, that is not a question, question is, adding a folder to resources and using items from that folder. Since I will have a large amount of pictures and sounds and it can get confusing if they are all piled in one folder of resources.

Comment: Does this work?
ThisBtnImg.Image = Properties.Resources.ThisButton

Comment: Nope. It's not in resource directory it s in resources/Buttons.

Comment: I tried doing this. Created a folder under resources and added an image. I then added the image as resource. The resource was added as
Properties.Resources.<ImageName> even if it was under a subforlder. If your image under the subforlder has the same name as an image in root folder then it mihght have been imported with name <ImageName>1.

Comment: You have selected pictures build action as resources?

Comment: No, you said you did what I described in my answser. If you embedded the resource with build action, take a look at this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: I am having very hard time understanding you o.O

Answer (score 0):

See this answer [How to add resources in separate folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859699/how-to-add-resources-in-separate-folders)

You need to set the build action for the folder to "embedded resource". Then you can access the files like this

```
using(Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<root namespace for the      assembly>.<folder name>.<image file name>"))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```