# Adding an image to a project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I added a folder to my project by right clicking on the project and adding a new folder. Now I added the image to the folder (using copy paste in Windows File Explorer), but the solution explorer is not showing my added image. I did refresh the solution as well.

Also, in that folder, there is no option of adding an image, only Visual Studio files (new items etc)..

Why isn't Solution Explorer showing my image?

Comment: What do you mean "copy paste in windows"? You just need to have a existing file and then just open the context menu on your folder and then choose "Add" -> "Existing item..."

Answer (score 56, accepted):

- You just need to have an existing file, open the context menu on your folder , and then choose `Add` => `Existing item...`

  [image]
- If you have the **file already placed within your project structure**, but it is not yet included, you can do so by making them visible in the solution explorer

  [image]

and then include them via the file context menu
  [image]

Comment: What if the files (e.g. images) are adding in runtime/production? Will the program still recognize these files?

Comment: @KMC If you mean load and use images during runtime, then yes, ofcourse you can. What do you mean by recognize?

Comment: @derape I am trying to follow your answer, but for some reason "Include in Project" is not showing...it is grayed out. Any idea why?

Comment: @Paul not sure why. Make sure you are able to add new files to the project; that the file is still available and is readable.

Answer (score 7):

If you're having an issue where the Resources added are images and are not getting copied to your build folder on compiling. You need to change the "Build Action" to None from Resource ( which is the default) and change the Copy to "If Newer" or "Always" as shown below :

[image]

Comment: Didn't work, changed the build action back to none, then it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You need to turn on `Show All Files` option on solution pane toolbar and include this file manually.

Answer (score 4):

Click on the Project in Visual Studio and then click on the button titled "Show all files" on the Solution Explorer toolbar. That will show files that aren't in the project. Now you'll see that image, right click in it, and select "Include in project" and that will add the image to the project!