# clickonce deployment setup , gif image not working after install in a different computer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, clickonce, setup-deployment

I am trying to deployment a setup for my WPF c# application. i suppose to do it using clickonce because it allow to auto update when i do any update in my application.

Actually i create a setup for my  application. when i install that app in a different computer, it works...when i do some update my app, it automatically detect when program launching and user can install new update and run the app.

But it does not show any gif images when program running. when i install the app in a different computer, it create a desktop shortcut and start menu icon. when i run the program via shortcut or start menu, it does not show any gif images. it work fine without showing gif images.

app installed in

```
C:\Users\dilan\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\TA5EZNVO.D56\TY5K2KDD.7B6\rcu_..tion_d1f05f20b6f0835a_0001.0000_d9a8ddd982f2efb7
```

i went to this location and double click the exe file. then app is running with showing gif images.but it does not update. update only happen when run the app via desktop short cut or start menu.

i tested the app by putting image files in to Images folder , Resources folder...but it does not work..

i think i missed some points when creating setup file. can anyone help me , how to deploy a setup file using clickonce , that app work with gif iamges also.

Here is how XAML looks like:

```
<Image gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/tapcard.gif" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
```

Comment: What are the "Build Action" and "Copy to Output Directory" properties set to on your image?

Comment: Build Action set to content and Copy to Output Directory set to copy Always

Comment: If you clear your cache (C:\Users\dilan\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0) does that help?

Comment: yes...i cleared the installed folder and reinstall the setup...but gif images are not working..

Answer (score 0):

I might not have inculded your images in your project. 
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15475131/2224701). You need to right click the file in Solution Explorer and then `Include in project` .

When you include them, the Build Action of the image file would be set to `Resource` - no need to copy images individually (`Copy to Output Directory` should be by default set to `Do not copy`).

Let's say you have a WPF project in the folder `Images` named `Progress.gif`.
In code behind you reference it like this:

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Progress.gif", UriKind.Absolute))
```

In XAML you reference the image simply like this

```
<Image Source="./Images/Progress.gif" >
```

You can use [another URI scheme as well](http://nerddawg.blogspot.sk/2005/11/resources-in-windows-presentation.html), e. g. `pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/tapcard.gif` refers to an image that is located on  the server where the app was deployed.

> If you do not want to be bound by the restrictions of having your
>   application resources declared at compile time, there is another
>   option for you. No, this doesn't involve using fully qualified Uris to
>   reference resources over the internet. Although, that is indeed
>   supported. WPF provides you with an abstraction for the application's
>   conceptual site of origin i.e. the location from where the application
>   was deployed. For instance, if your application was launched from
>   http://nerddawg.blogspot.com, then your application's site of origin
>   is http://nerddawg.blogspot.com. To access an image at
>   images/AuntDahlia.gif at that location, you would specify in markup:
>   `<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/images/AuntDahlia.jpg" />`

So you check in the properties of your WPF project on Publis tab the Publish location or Installation folder URL (if specified). If installation URL is e.g. `http://myserver:8080` then you need to verify from the client, that the file `http://myserver:8080/Images/tapcard.gif` exists by typing this url into a browser. Depending on the folder structure of your web you might need to copy the file manually there.

`pack://siteoforigin:` means you are getting the resource over the network from the web or file server.

Comment: hi...Thank you for your answer..but unfortunately it does not work for me.

Comment: hi...Thank you for your answer..but unfortunately it does not work for me.
i changed the build in action option  of images into Resources and Do not Copy, and deployed. 
But gif images are not displayed. I checked the installed folder in 
C:\Users\dilan\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\CTVXXJKO.7P3\95O1GREO.67D\rcu_..tion_10be6a976bd0b12e_0001.0000_1b180cadf5bc82d7.

Comment: C:\Users\dilan\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\CTVXXJKO.7P3\95O1GREO.67D\rcu_..tion_10be6a976bd0b12e_0001.0000_1b180cadf5bc82d7. 

I there also, there is no image folder. Then i checked the app without install , just by pressing F5 in visual studio. 
then visual studio also does not show gif image..my source code is here.....

<Image gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/tapcard.gif" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>