# access an excluded files/folder after publish a project in asp dot net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

is that possible to access an excluded  files/folder after publish a project in asp dot net web application?
I'm uploading image and save the location path in the database. when I published the project in IIS I want to exclude the image folder from the project. So that my image is not showing. Is it possible to access an excluded file from the run time?

Comment: Please provide information about your workflow and specific files that you're trying to publish. Where is this image located? How are you copying it to the server? How are you trying to access this image?

Comment: I upload the image under project folder, image is located in project folder. when I publish the project in IIS from VS-2017 image folder is excluded. So images not displaying

Comment: Sounds like your question is "How to include images in your build in visual studio". See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474366/adding-an-image-to-a-project-in-visual-studio