# folder missing in resources

Tags: c#, resources

I have the following code for showing an image:

```
Image im = new Image();
im.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Icons.login.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
im.Height = 200;
im.Width = 200;
icons.Add(new IconImagesForDummies() { Name = str, Image = im });
```

The `Image` class belongs to `System.Windows.Controls.Image`. I have added a folder to store images separately from Resources folder (named Icons). But I have set the `build action` property of all images to `Embed Resource` and they have been set to `Copy Always`. I do not know why I can not see the images. I'm using `WPF`. During debugging I found out that the image path was fine and it founded that, but I do not know the reason, the image was not showed. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859699/how-to-add-resources-in-separate-folders) but was useless.

Is there something wrong with the `Uri`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: maybe its just this simple

```
im.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Icons\login.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
```

Edit: changing build action to content works.

Comment: actually I need my app to be portable, I need relative path

Comment: I changed the build action to content and it did the job, Edit your answer to close the question. thanks